# Git Alias for Message with Argument

Tags: git, alias, msysgit

I am using msysgit to run Git on a Windows box and I'm interested in establishing an alias for a common task: committing.

In our environment, our messages need to follow a certain format: 'jira-BL-[TICKET_NUMBER]- [MESSAGE]'. For this alias, I'd like to parameterize the [TICKET_NUMBER] and [MESSAGE] parts to eliminate typos that break our build system, so I could call it like this:

```
git ca 1234 'Fixed bug'
```

Right now, I have this in my .gitconfig (based on some googling/experimenting):

```
ca = "!sh -c 'git commit -am 'jira:BL-$1 - $2''" -;
```

Which gets me an actual commit message of "jira:BL-1234" but the second part of the message is completely lost. I know that git can handle parameters on its own (without the shell call), but from what I've seen, it can't handle them in the way I'd like here. What am I missing or am I not going to be able to do this?

Comment: Using a commit message like this isn't, on the long term, a good idea…

Comment: @user3426575 what do you mean? I have to manually do this right now, and it certainly isn't how I would choose to run things, but it is how things have to be done.

Comment: Talk to whoever insists on this naming scheme. The primary function of a commit message is to tell people (that is, other people as well as yourself, at some point in the future) what the purpose of the commit is, which action has been taken and why it has been done that way. Putting a set of numbers in there thwarts the very reason commit messages exist. — That doesn't mean you can't reference bugs from the commit message. In fact, you should. The usual way to do so is to add a line `Closes-bug:`, `Relates-to-bug:`, etc. at the *end* of the message.

Comment: @user3426575 This is a legacy system with deeply entrenched attitudes; I'm just along for the ride, short-term. In fact, officially this app uses SVN; I'm using git-svn locally. I don't disagree with anything you said, but there's a snowball's chance of the existing system changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ca = "!sh -c 'git commit -am \"jira:BL-$1 - $2\"'" -;
```

seems to be closer. I'm not sure I'd say this macro makes life easier :/

Perhaps you can select your favourite editor as the commit editor and make a macro/abbreviation there that does what you need

Comment: Thanks, yes, this does seem to work. I am just so sick of manually typing that formatting that I wanted to explore using an alias, and at least I have a working one now. It remains to be seen if I actually use it...